# Print JasperReports Table From a Hashtable, without a DB Connection

Tags: java, database, printing, jasper-reports, hashtable

I want to print a price quotation using JasperReports.
I have already coded the Invoice printing function and its working.
I am going to customize the same template and same code here.
In the case of invoice, I saved the invoice data to the DB first, and then get those data in the Jasper report print.

But the problem here in the quotation is, I want to print the data which is not saved in the database. I don't want to save the quotation data to the Database.
I have all the quotation data in a Hashtable. 
How can I print it as a table using JasperReports?

This is how a field looks like in the detail band, in the Invoice.

```
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="7" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <paragraph spacingBefore="1"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Item_Code}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: are you saying you are wanting to use the existing report, but instead of using the sql query in it you want to use the data in your hashtable?

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in a Hashtable, you can pass it to the report in a parameter. I think that's what you're looking for... but it's not entirely clear.